# vline Chrome vs Firefox place video call

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, vline

I have 2 clients opened, 1 on Google Chrome and Firefox (both are latest version). When I make call from Firefox, the Chrome client can receive the request. But when I make call from Chrome, the Firefox client does not see anything. Any idea? Thank you.

(Javascript within my Rails app)

```
    function call(userId) {
      if (session) {
        session.getPerson(userId)
                .done(function(person) {
                    person.startMedia();
                });
      }
    }


<a onclick="call('<%= userid %>')" href="javascript:void(0)">Call</a>
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Does it work if you make a call from Chrome to Chrome (one needs to be an incognito window)? Also, does a call with the Web Client (https://your-service-id.vline.com) work?

Comment: @timpham Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892800/vline-cross-browser-video-call-not-working to see if it's the same issue