# Vline cross browser video call not working

Tags: php, vline

I have implemented vLine API on one of the websites. It works fine when I use only chrome (Normal + incognito widnow) or firefox (Normal + Private browsing).

But if I use two different browsers say Chrome and Firefox then I get following error.

```
 [130919 16:21:10.77] [vline.mediaSession] GET_LOCAL_STREAM_FAILED (Do you have a camera and have you given permission to access it? [https://vline.com/developer/docs/debugging#get_local_stream_failed])
```

I have checked my cam settings and everything is allowed and the site is also in the white list of sites allowed to access my cam and microphone. But still I get above error.

The site is running on SSL.

Can anyone please help to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What versions of Chrome and Firefox and what OS?

Comment: @tomvLine Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m and Firefox 23.0.1. Also I have used the PHP demo available on vLine.com for integration and this demo has the same problem as well.

Comment: We've tested that configuration and it should work (I just double-checked). Can you try making the call in the Web Client (your-service-id.vline.com)? Also, you may want to try making the call between two separate computers in case Firefox and Chrome are somehow unable to share the camera (though like I said it works for me).

Comment: @tomvLine Thanks Tom this works from two different computers. Also I can't get it work on I-Phone and Android phones. The site is responsive but the call button doesn't make any call on mobile phones Safari and Chrome browsers.

Comment: WebRTC is supported in Chrome for Android (29 and higher), but not Chrome for iOS or Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to sum up the comments in an answer now that everything seems to be resolved.

Calls between Firefox and Chrome do work as expected, but Jay was having problems when trying to run Chrome and Firefox on the same computer and make a call. This works on the machines that I have tested, but based on the error pasted in the question, it looks like one of the browsers was failing to acquire the camera; we've occasionally [seen issues](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151246) with the browsers not acquiring/releasing the camera correctly, so that's likely the cause of the problem he was seeing. We will continue to try to reproduce this on different platforms and file a bug with the browsers.

Jay confirmed that calling between two different computers did work correctly.

**UPDATE:** I was able to reproduce this on Windows. Here's the Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=918938